# Got let go with 2 weeks notice being asked to share ideas and strategies for company

Tags: professionalism, unemployment-benefits

I just got let go from the company, was withheld discretionary bonus, not given a reason I was let go. Yet I'm being asked to share project details and strategies I've been working on in two meetings in person with the CEO. Two days before my final days. Should I decline or accept?

Comment: "let go" implies that you are no longer employed.  If you have a final two days you are presumably still employed, are you going to be paid for those two days?

Comment: I am being employed for those two days

Comment: If that is the case, then attend the meetings and provide the feedback that they are asking for.  That is the professional thing to do.

Comment: Where in the world are you? Is it normal/legal to have been "let go" this way? What is an "discretionary bonus"?

Comment: This question has way too little info on the background of the story, so I voted to close it. That info makes a LOT of difference when dealing with the "exit".

Comment: "*yet I’m being asked to share Project details and strategie*" Isn't this just equivalent to asking you to hand off your work so long as you are still within the period of notice and still working for the company.

Comment: You can always quit two days early for undisclosed personal reasons.  Then if they need something from you, you can ask for something in return.  Or take PTO if you have it.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft , Hey boss, cough, cough, feeling a bit under the weather with all this stress.... PTO looks like a good idea right now to get me on the mend.

Comment: This question really reads like "Can I engage in petty bs because I'm mad that I got fired?" This is really not a game you want to play - you can't win, but there's a nonzero chance you could really lose...

Comment: Your question got cut off

Comment: Sorry for your loss. Usually, if you are let go that means you are terminated that day and can leave. That's typical in most right to work states.....which means there are no rules. You can also walk away from a job. Two weeks notice is common courtesy, but younger generations today don't follow that today, anyway. My advice is take the High Road, and give that nervous CEO everything he/she wants and then quietly leave. Show character. Don't burn bridges accept with your boss who has burned his. Ive been let go then hired back by a CEO. All you ever have is your Integrity and Reputation. ;)

Comment: If the CEO themselves fired you, modify your contact list in your phone, so everything from work goes to voicemail, otherwise proceed in giving the CEO whatever they requested. You might prove to them they actually need you.

Comment: Flagged for reopen.

Comment: If you are asked to share "things you have been working on", the company has _already_ paid you for that work, it is legitimately the company's intellectual property, and you literally owe it to them to make a reasonable effort to transfer that knowledge before leaving.

Answer (score -49, accepted):

If you've been fired and now they want information - here is how I would answer it:

"My Contracting rate is $xxx per hour, I estimate that to fully divulge all the information and expertise I am in possession of will take a total of Y hours.

Please approve a purchase order for $xxxx and pay in advance and I will gladly assist"

Others are saying that you should play nice etc. - but they have already given you your marching orders. You are not obligated to play nice.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142880/discussion-on-answer-by-thedemonlord-got-let-go-with-2-weeks-notice-being-asked); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I think this is absolutely the right response if they asked you after they shut off your email address and took your laptop. If it happens before then, it would be gracious of you to forward whatever notes you took (assuming you took any, wink wink nudge nudge)

Comment: It's unclear if this answer is assuming a situation before the last day of employment, or after the last day of employment. Suggest it would be improved by clarifying the presumed context.

Comment: If it's after the OP has already been terminated, sure tell them tough luck. But, at least to me, it doesn't sound like that is the case here in which case OP is still within notice and still being employed and paid by the company and this just sounds like handing off their work.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: "*Two days before my final days.*" says the question. So this answer misses the target, as OP is still an employee with duties. It's either after the last day (or it would be illegal to tell the company this) or the question was misread maybe...

Comment: @OldPadawan: Yes, that's why I suggest the author of this answer edit it to clarify how they read the question.

Comment: I was pretty clear in the previous, archived comments - find a legitimate way to skip the last 2 days of work and then charge them.

Comment: The advice in this answer is attempt to extort the employer, and then when that doesn't work, commit fraud.

Comment: @LeLetter the more significant criterion is whether you're still officially employed, that is, receiving salary (not including severance pay).  They can shut down your access to any system or all systems before the last day of employment (most employees will be unauthorized on at least some systems throughout their employment).  That said, if you don't want to "play nice," as this answer has it, consider the consequences: if they terminate you for cause instead of without reason you can lose unemployment benefits.

Comment: @TheDemonLord: Surely you know that comments aren't persistent. Reiterate that the answer would be clarified by editing in that context.

Comment: This answer might win "most downvoted accepted answer"!

Comment: This is terrible advice... As my old man used to say: "*when they go low, don't follow. Keep your head upright and go high*". It's not because you're let go that your have to put yourself off-limit and outlaw

Comment: Your reputation with The Board has decreased. 

Comment: @Stef : Yup.  At the time of this writing, it shows -35.  To clarify, that's 20 positive votes that increased reputation each by 10, and 55 negative votes that each decreased reputation by 2.  So that's +200 from positive votes, and -110 from negative votes.  The poster has, at time of this writing, profited 90 reputation points from an answer that looks like is rated at -35 (just from the votes, not counting the acceptance bonus which I expect did push it over 100 reputation points gained at the time of this writing).

Comment: @Stef I might have to run a query through the SE explorer to see where this answer ranks in the metric - quite interesting.

Comment: @Voo One step ahead of ya https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7162/presenting-the-worst-accepted-answers

Comment: @toogam: Yup. And all of this for a quick minimum-effort answer which is basically cut&paste from "the usual" meme in this regard, at least for US based companies.  I have some pity with people living in a hard world like that where there is minimum cooperation and goodwill between employees and their companies. :/

Comment: OP has **not** finished working with this company yet. He just had the 2 weeks notice. He is still an employee. your answer would work *after* the end of the notice, but before it asking money to fulfil your employer's request is not only rude but absolutely unfounded.

Comment: @Gregory Rookie mistake, I should've known that the answer already exists on SO somewhere.

Comment: @Stef: Per Gregory's link, this answer is on track to blow away the previous record-holder by a factor of 2.

Comment: @AnoE  - Now, I take exception to the accusation of a Copy-Paste Answer. Now sure, this is a contentious answer, lots disagree with it (understandable why) but a lot also agree with it. Why? Whether OP was Fired or their role was disestablished (we don't know) - it's clear that *from the actions of the company* they are in possession of Vital knowledge - and being asked, 2 days before you are made redundant for information is also highly unprofessional - it's an asshole move. Other people are saying take the high road - that's noble, I'm not. Part 1.

Comment: @AnoE part 2 - If the roles were reversed, do you think the Company would likewise be making such accommodations? Of course not, they would charge. If the OP had left on good terms with the Company, I would absolutely advocate that they help out - hell, I've done it in the past with companies I've left of my own choice. But this is not the case. The OP has leverage and my advice is to monetize that leverage - what happens next is either the OP gets a nice severance bonus or the company doesn't want to pay and finds the information out another way (or accepts the loss).

Comment: @GregoryCurrie - I had a look at your query - we'll need a new one - since you've filtered out closed questions - otherwise I would be at the top.

Comment: Finally - in addition, considering when the OP was let go and was denied a Bonus - that increases the 'Screw them, they can pay through the nose' factor - which many of you seem to be ignoring. It doesn't sound to me like the company acted entirely in good faith - therefore there's no reason for the OP to act in Good Faith either. Is it the optimal outcome? Of course not, but then we have the word 'Doormat' for someone who lets themselves be screwed over for a reason. I'm advocating the most disagreeable response - to fight fire, with fire.

Comment: @TheDemonLord That is a good analogy, because the usual result of fighting fire with fire is that you get burned.

Comment: @TheDemonLord, we can discuss this back and forth ad nauseam. I prefer not to act spiteful in general, and see no benefit whatsoever in doing so in this case. Maybe OP was done wrong, maybe not, but presumably the company acted within its contractual/lawful limits. It's not like I am "ignoring" the "screw them" factor, but I generally never "screw" anybody, at least not consciously. I believe that being awful to others eventually always catches up with you, and if it's only in your own mind (aside from it giving me no joy or any other tangible benefits).

Answer (score 102):

As hard as this will be, leaving a company gracefully is a great quality to have.

Even if it may be thankless.

Leaving spitefully and burning bridges at the very best has no winners in the short term and could damage your reputation and future contacts in your network in the long term.

Attend the meetings and do your best, you are still being paid.

Comment: "A professional is someone who tries to do their best work even when they don't want to."

Comment: Agreed. It's a small world; you'll meet some of these people elsewhere in your career.

Comment: @keshlam - Sounds a lot like an adage made by managers who want to get away with mistreating people because they know they won't retaliate "because professionalism". I'd be inclined to agree with you if he was let go properly. However, firing someone without cause, without justification, and witholding a bonus that they had, in the absense of a reason to fire them, likely earned, isn't professionalism.

Comment: You owe your company as much loyalty as they show you - otherwise you are being exploited. In today's world, there is not much duty in either direction. Don't knock everything over and poop on the desks - *that* would be unprofessional - and hand over what is owed - but don't bend over backwards to please them.

Comment: @ScottishTapWater For me it's about self-respect, not anyone else's. If you don't want to be paid for those remaining two weeks, feel free to say so and ask to be terminated immediately. If you're going to take the pay, do the work to exit cleanly. Pettiness doesn't look good on anyone, under any circumstances.

Comment: Just get the bonus confirmation and conditions in writing as part of your termination letter, or better, get the payment first! Last thing you want to do is be gracious and get stiffed!

Comment: @keshlam immediate termination may not be possible under local labor law, or it may (because the employee requested it) constitute a waiver of separation entitlements.

Comment: @phoog True. But for me it comes back to those same points;  I will feel better in the long run if I'm not petulant in the short run. Many will feel differently, but short of actual abuse or being escorted off the premises and told not to come back I consider this part of what I committed to when I took the job.

Answer (score 83):

> I’m being asked to share Project details and strategies I’ve been working on in two meetings in person with the CEO.

Those details and strategies do not belong to you. You have worked on them on company time and been paid for it. The company owns them. You are in possession of them, just like you would be in possession of the car keys to the company car. That does not mean you get to keep it when they fire you and it does not mean you get to withhold the keys from them. You have to give them back. You also have to give them their knowledge.

The stories you hear, where people charge big sums of money for their services, that is *after* they left. And they do not charge for the *knowledge* (which remember, doesn't actually belong to the employee) but for the time spent on the transfer of said knowledge. You cannot do that right now, because you are still under contract to give them your time for money and they get to decide how to spend that time. A meeting for knowledge transfer is certainly within the bounds of your current contract.

If you refuse, they have a reason to terminate you for cause. I don't know what that means in your juristiction, but it's probably worse than "being let go" and you will certainly lose any reference you may have had there, any goodwill or favors you may need along the road. You may even face a lawsuit, that their company lawyer will do on company time and money, while your defense lawyer drains your personal bank account.

So go in there, and do your job one last time. That's what they pay you for, that is what you agreed to in your contract.

Comment: _"The company owns them"_ -- _"[don't] belong to the employee"_ -- I find this framing sloppy, if not dystopian. Thoughts can't be owned, and if they could, the company could retrieve them post-employment, not by request but on demand. There's a case if said thoughts are a product of significant company investment, but them being acquired simply "on company time" doesn't cut it, any more than it does for a patentable invention. I agree they're entitled _in this case_ in sense of paid delivery of goods or services, but that reads differently.

Answer (score 46):

Two days before the end of the notice period you are still employed, so you still have to follow orders.

Since you are meeting the CEO, it’s a good opportunity to ask them first why you were laid off, why your bonus was withheld, and whether that could be changed. It’s worth asking, and you are definitely allowed to do that. It’s even possible that some money-pincher withheld your bonus, and the CEO would have disagreed and changes it for you.

In the USA, it is in many states legal to quit on the spot. That will cost you two days earnings, probably won’t help with the reference either. You can ask the CEO first what reason you would have to not just quit. (But ask an employment lawyer first). In Europe, you can’t do that.

Comment: This. Since the CEO is the head of the company they can override someone lower down if they want to. You have nothing to lose here.

Comment: "Two days before... you are still employed" This is the best answer for your career. The world, when it comes to employment, is surprisingly small - don't learn lesson that the hard way.

Comment: DON'T QUIT OUT OF SPITE!
If you quit, you're likely to be ineligible for any kind of unemployment benefits.

Comment: @Dancrumb - They can’t quit they were already fired. They are likely under no obligation to work those 2 weeks. It’s typically just a formality. With that said, my advice to the author would change, based on whomever fired them at the company

Comment: If you are fired, and it is two days before the end of the notice period, and you are in a place where you can quit without notice, you can absolutely quit. If you don't quit you are employed to the end of your notice period. You get paid and you are absolutely obliged to work. @Dancrumb Obviously you would have looked for another job instead of relying on unemployment insurance.

Comment: @gnasher729 I wouldn't say obviously. Some people may think they are still eligible for benefits because they had already been fired before they quit.

Answer (score 14):

Do what they ask. Since you are still working there, just be a pro and do it. Being pro *may* also be helpful in securing a better/good reference for your next job.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently working for that company. You have been paid for all the work you have done and it belongs to your current company. They are 100% entiteled to all your work, documentation, and your time in handing off the project to others.

You would be a real douchebag if you didn't help facilitate the transfer, because you would be incredibly outraged if the positions were reversed. If for no other reason, talk with the CEO and ask what kind of recommendation he would give you as a reference, and hand off everything as a gracefully as possible.

Your thought should be: "How can I move on and improve my current state" NOT "How can I royally screw over this company as I'm leaving".

Answer (score 2):

Something other answers miss a little is that refusal to do your job and work with your employer, can constitute grounds for summary dismissal with cause.

So, if your position was made redundant, and you were eligible for unemployment benefits, being terminated with cause can change that situation.

In addition, refusal to work can also be constituted as resigning under certain circumstances, which could also impact the ability to get unemployment benefits as well.

To me, I don't see a clear reason why you'd jeopardise that.

Answer (score -5):

If you don't want to be helpful, but still don't want to be a major PITA, call in sick the last two days. If they then want you to provide information when you get better, you can do that at an hourly rate.

Comment: How is pretending to be sick to avoid sharing information the company needs *not* intentionally being a major PITA?

Comment: Seriously, don't ever do this unless you can provide evidence that you were actually sick, otherwise you're exposing yourself to the extortion claims mentioned in comments as a possible consequence of other answers here. Lying about your availability in order to force a payment later on is petty and, in any reasonable jurisdiction, actionable.

Comment: If they asked for a 'turn over' meeting and you avoid it, **I'd say you're morally obligated** to give them the information when you are no longer sick. Even if you disagree with or dislike the word "moral" I'd advise you it is in your best interests long-term to do it this way anyway. *I've seen it done the other way,* and the consequences can come back to bite you years or even decades later. "Oh I just cannot understand why that happened!" will be something you'll find yourself saying years later.

Comment: @Spratty I don't believe your claim for a second. If you say you got a stomach bug, why should anyone question that? They are happy if you don't show up under such circumstances. List three court cases where someone has gotten into trouble for this. I am not holding my breath.

Comment: @J.ChrisCompton Not really. If you are sick under "regular" circumstances, no one expects you to catch up with the work you didn't do when you were sick. Imagine the OP had some monotonous work like receptionist or mailman and happened to be sick the last few days of his employment, should he come back next week and answer as many phone calls or deliver as many letters he otherwise would have handled the last few days?

Comment: @d-b - I'm not claiming you would automatically get in trouble for pretending to have a stomach upset; I am claiming it is a bad idea to do so specifically so you can then charge someone for your time at a later date; that is clearly attempting to obtain money by deception. I don't have any court cases to cite immediately and have no idea how to craft a search to see if there have been any; however the point stands - lying in order to extract money is, well, lying in order to extract money; you can find any number of cases of people sued/prosecuted for that.

Comment: @Spratty Well, no one is forcing the former employer to use the services of the former employee. Therefore, it is not an attempt to "extract money".

Comment: @d-b - no, there's no force involved, but the answer specifically states that the OP could call in sick and then provide the information that should have been given as part of the normal exit process _for an hourly rate_ later on; that's a very clear attempt to extract money. Also, if the OP is the only person who can provide that handover info, they would be forcing the employer to either pay out or miss out entirely; make of that what you will in terms of force.

Comment: @d-b "If you are sick under 'regular' circumstances, no one expects you to catch up with the work you didn't do when you were sick."  Yes, I agree. However, in this instance the OP *isn't actually sick.*

Comment: @J.ChrisCompton Well, he is sick of is employer ;-)

Comment: @d-b -grin- Yeah, I get that part... but.